# Running tests on Django multitable inheritance model causes IntegrityError

Tags: django, django-models, pytest

Running tests on Django multitable inheritance model causes IntegrityError

Hello, I created a parent class and two children classes like that

```py
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
   ....

class B(A):
   ....

class C(A):
   ....
```

Whenever I try to run tests that create instance of class B I get this error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_b_pkey"
E               DETAIL:  Key (a_ptr_id)=(2) already exists.
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create multiple instances of the model with the same ID. Are you passing an explicit ID when creating them? You need to share what your tests are doing.

Comment: I did not fix this bug. I changed my models in database to bypass this problem. 

I did not explicitly assign ID, I just used factory to create model e.g. 

model_a = AFactory()
model_b = BFactory()

Comment: I think that this problem is caused either by testing library not clearing all tables after test or factory library not tracking ids correctly